# optional variable names in array - need to create an instance

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, dynamic

I'm working with a framework and have to change some things for my project.

The original is

```
      var tree:FBQuadTree? = nil
      ...
      if tree == nil {
        tree = FBQuadTree()
      }
```

I need always a custom number of trees. So my consideration was that I use an array for this.

```
var tree:[FBQuadTree?] = []
...
if tree[number] == nil {
   tree[number] = FBQuadTree()
}
```

But I don't know how to fill my new tree array. Sure I could do smth. like this:

```
let element:FBQuadTree?
layersTree.append(element)
```

Okay, but my problem is that number of elements isn't static. So sometimes there is just one element, sometimes a lot more.

Is that possible what I want to do?

the whole thing:

```
var array:[FBQuadTree] = []

//fill
for i in 0..<MyDynamicSize {
array.append(//how to fill?)
}

//give new values
for i in 0..<MyDynamicSize {
array[i] = FBQuadTree() 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're just trying to get an `Array` of a `myDynamicSize`* number of `FBQuadTree` instances, you can use [`init(repeating:count:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/array/1641692-init).

```
var array = [FBQuadTree](count: myDynamicSize, repeatedValue: FBQuadTree())
```

Sidenote: by convention, types start with capitals, whereas variable names start with lowercase letters. So `myDynamicSize`, rather than `MyDynamicSize`

Answer (score -1):

please try this

```
var array:[FBQuadTree?] = []

//fill
for i in 0..<MyDynamicSize {
    array.append(nil)
}
```